# Looking for an easy method of rearranging $W^2=\frac{T+W-1}{T}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Rearrange the formula $(1)$ to make $W$ the subject

$$W^2=\frac{T+W-1}{T}\tag1$$
$$W^2T=T+W-1$$
$$W^2T-W=T-1$$
$$W^2-\frac{W}{T}=1-\frac{1}{T}$$
Using complete the square method
$$\left(W-\frac{1}{2T}\right)^2=1-\frac{1}{T}+\frac{1}{4T^2}$$
$$\left(W-\frac{1}{2T}\right)^2=\frac{4T^2-4T+1}{4T^2}$$
$$\left(W-\frac{1}{2T}\right)^2=\frac{(2T-1)^2}{4T^2}$$
$$W-\frac{1}{2T}=\pm\frac{(2T-1)}{2T}$$

$$W=\frac{1-T}{T}$$

**Is there is an elegant method (or an easy way) of answering this question without doing completing the square method?**

Answer (score 1):

Make W the subject of
$$W^2=\frac{T+W-1}{T}$$
To avoid using the quadratic formula, we do the following, make $T$ the subject

$$W^2T=T+W-1$$
$$W^2T-T=W-1$$
$$T(W^2-1)=W-1$$
$$T=\frac{W-1}{W^2-1}=\frac{W-1}{(W-1)(W+1)}=\frac{1}{W+1}$$

Now rearrange this $T=\frac{1}{W+1}$ to make W the subject

$$TW+T=1$$
$$W=\frac{1-T}{T}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a quadratic equation in $\text{W}$ so we can use:

$$\text{a}x^2+\text{b}x+\text{c}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{-\text{b}\pm\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\text{a}\text{c}}}{2\text{a}}\tag1$$

Answer (score 0):

No. What you have is a quadratic equation in $W$. In order to solve it, you need to complete the square, or use something of equivalent "power", such as the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

Note
$$W^2-\frac{T+W-1}{T}=W^2- 1-\frac1T(W-1)
= (W-1)(W+1-\frac1T)=0$$